# Restarting a shell script with a signal

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a script that runs and outputs to my panel. What I'm trying to do is to restart the script from another script by sending a siganl to it.

Script 1 (panel_script):

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "exec panel_script" SIGTRAP

while true; do
        echo "status"
        sleep 10
done
```

Script 2:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill -x -SIGTRAP panel_script
```

Comment: Please explain what your problem is. What errors are you getting, and why isn't it doing what you expect?

Comment: Huh? What's a *"panel"* please? And what's the point of restarting this script, it's only going to run `echo status` again exactly the same as if you didn't restart it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell `status` is just a placeholder for a command that outputs the current desktop. I'm currently using bspwm and have a rule that runs the second script every time I change the desktop. This information is displayed on the top corner of the screen on a panel.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I'm trying to restart the first script from the second with `exec`. Because it's slow when I try to kill it and start it again `pkill -x lemonpanel && exec lemonpanel`. It worked when I used `SIGINT` but that only worked from keyboard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trap "exec $0" EXIT` and `pkill -f panel_script`.

You did not write that you would ever want to stop the script again.

Comment: The second script is supposed to run every time i change the current desktop. It's outputting to a panel on the top of the screen that displays the current working desktop. I currently refresh it with `pkill -x lemonpanel && exec lemonpanel` in the second script but that is noticeably slow.